# How to navigate to other page when location.state is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state

I have a react application where I pass state via react router and access the state using location in the target component/page. It works perfect, however when I close the tab and paste the exact same url to that page in another tab it crashes and says `Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')`. This is how I am accessing the state:

```
const { filter, mode } = location?.state[1];
```

I want to navigate to home page if the location state is null.

I have tried the following but does not seem to work.

```
if (location.state === null) {
  navigate("/");
}

const { filter, mode } = location?.state[1];
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is still running after navigate if you don't return

```
if (location.state===null) {
  navigate("/");
  return null;
}

const { filter, mode } = location?.state[1];
```

Comment: i added the return and now it says` Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null`

Comment: Fixed, return `null` instead

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the logic between issuing the imperative navigation action ***as a side-effect***, and returning null from the component so you are not accidentally accessing null or undefined state.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.state === null) {
    navigate("/");
  }
}, []);

const { filter, mode } = location?.state[1];

if (!location.state) {
  return null;
}
```

Alternatively you could simply return the `Navigate` component instead. Just ensure that any and all React hooks are unconditionally called prior to any early returns from the React function body.

Example:

```
...

if (location.state === null) {
  return <Navigate to="/" />;
}

const { filter, mode } = location?.state[1];
```

Comment: the second method worked as well for me, however the not operator causes a bug it should be just location.state === null

Comment: @lui Oops, yeah, `!state === null` doesn't make any sense, it should be `state !== null` ‍♂️ if that's what you needed, but yeah, if the state ***is*** null that is when you want to navigate and return null, or render the `Navigate`. Sorry for any confusion.